# Power output equivalent of 18V battery

Tags: batteries

A 18 V 4 Ah battery contains 10 cells.
A 18650 cell can have a max continuous discharge rate of 20 A.

Does that mean that a typical 18 V 4 Ah battery can theoretically provide the tool the equivalent of 3600 watt of power? (10 * 20 A * 18 V = 3600 W)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

The 10 cells are likely to be connected in series, each giving 1.8 V. Assuming the max discharge per cell is 20 A as per your answer, then the battery can give 20*18 = 360 W for a short time.

The 4 Ah part of the spec is important. The total power within the battery is 18 V*4 Ah = 72 Wh. If you try and draw the 360 W then you will get 72/360 hours = 0.2 * 60 minutes = 12 minutes use. These are all best case values. It may last a lot less as the 4 Ah will be the maximum power at the most efficient rate of drain.

Comment: 18650 cells are lithium ion cells with a nominal voltage of 3.6V. A ten cell 18V pack is therefore 5s2p. Meaning that the max output power would be 40A*18V = 720watts.

Answer (score 4):

No. That should be approximately 720 Watt of maximum power.

Typical power tool cells are:

- Nominal Voltage: 3.6 V
- Rated Capacity: 1.5-2.0 Ah
- Max Continuous Discharge Current: 20-30 A

So An 18V 4 Ah battery has probably 5 in parallel and 2 in series:

- 5 × 3.6 V = 18 V
- 2 × 2 Ah = 4 Ah
- 2 × 20 A = 40 A (max)

Nominal voltage means that the voltage will vary in function of the discharge state of the battery, so

18 V × 40 A ≈ 720 W

is only an approximation.

Answer (score 1):

### Series

No, a battery comprised of a series of cells that each can supply 20 A will only supply 20 A. The same current runs through all cells. A 10-cell 18 V battery uses cells that each produce only 1.8 V. You connect them in series to produce a higher voltage useful for driving an electric motor.

This gives a power output of 18 x 20 = 360 Watts.

---

### Parallel

If the cells were reconnected in parallel (which is usually unsafe), You could produce 10 x 20 = 200 Amps but only at 1.8 V.

The power output would be 10 x 20 x 1.8 = 360 Watts. The same. However you would need much thicker wires to carry the current and/or the power losses in the wires would be higher.

---

### 18650

The 18650 is a 3.7 V 2200 mAh cell. To produce a 18 V, 2200 mAh battery you would connect five of them in series. To produce a 4 Ah (4000 mAh) battery you would use ten cells in a combination of parallel and series.

According to one [data sheet](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/1781Battery_2200mAh.pdf) The maximum continuous discharge is 2.2 A (2200 mA) not 20A. In that case, drawing 20A for more than a few seconds will overheat the cell. The cell has overcurrent detection at 4 - 7 A.

Comment: 18650 and 26650 cells vary quite a bit in their maximum continuous discharge current. Often, a cell will come in two types: "energy"-optimized, which have a lower max current but higher energy content, and "power"-optimized, which favor higher current draw. "Power" cells even vary quite a bit by manufacturer, having to do with the internal geometry and composition of the cell. Then there are many compositions of lithium cell - LiFePO4, Li-Ion, LiMnO2, etc. This all sums up to a huge variance in capacity and max current drain depending on exact battery specifications.

Answer (score 1):

Going back to basics:  1 watt = 1 amp * 1 volt.  1 Ah is 1 amp delivered in 1 hour.   Let’s say an 18650 battery is rated for 3.7V and a maximum continuous discharge of 2.2 Ah, or 2.2 amps over 1 hour.  (Side note:  discharging at any higher rate my overheat the battery, thereby damaging it.)  5 batteries in series is 3.7V x 5 = 18.5V.  The series configuration stepped up the voltage, but continuous discharge current is the same, as the current limit applies to each battery in series.  Putting two banks of 5 18650 batteries delivering 18.5V at 2.2 amps in parallel will allow 2.2 amps to flow in two paths, stepping up the continuous discharge current of the 10 batteries to 4.4Ah.    So, in 1 hour, we have 4.4 amps times 18.5 volts, which equals 81.4 watts.  More specifically, that is 81.4 watt/hours, or .0814 kWh, the unit of electrical power on your electric bill. How can 10 batteries be generating in the 720 watt (watt/hour) range?  Think of a 528 watt hair drier or computer power supply.  To power this with 18650 batteries, you would need 33 in series to get 120 volts, and two banks of 33 (66 total) to get 4.4 amps.  That's why computer battery backups of any significant runtime are so darn big and heavy.

Answer (score 0):

10 cell 18 V using 18650 would be a series of 5 pairs of 18650 in parallel.

You are capped at 20x2x18 V then, so 720 watts.

Some have responded that 10 1.8 V batteries in series would max at 360 watts, but they mistaken since these cells are 3.6 V nominal so the amperage is doubled in the 2x5 configuration.

Answer (score 0):

It's 72 watts, times ah by volts and there you go. A 100 ah 12v battery gives 1200 watts if you could fully drain it in theory